# How to aggregate categorical variables using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following table.

```
+--------+-----------+-------------+
| group  | numerical | categorical |
+--------+-----------+-------------+
| group1 |        23 | cat1        |
| group1 |        31 | cat1        |
| group1 |        10 | cat2        |
| group2 |        23 | cat1        |
| group2 |        51 | cat2        |
| group2 |        03 | cat2        |
+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

I want to group by the column `group` and get the following output table which gives the `count` of each category in the `categorical` column as individual columns.

```
+--------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| group  | numerical_sum | categorical_cat1_size | categorical_cat2_size |
+--------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| group1 |            64 |                     2 |                     1 |
| group2 |            77 |                     1 |                     2 |
+--------+---------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

For the numerical column we can aggregate and `sum`, but how can we get the value count of each category in the `categorical` column as a separate column?

Note that using `pd.value_counts` doesn't help as it gives the following output.

```
pd.groupby(by='group').agg({
    'numerical': 'sum',
    'categorical': pd.value_counts
})


+--------+---------------+-------------+
| group  | numerical_sum | categorical |
+--------+---------------+-------------+
| group1 |            64 | [2,1]       |
| group2 |            67 | [1,2]       |
+--------+---------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine aggregation `sum` with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df = (df.groupby(by='group', as_index=False)
        .agg({'numerical': 'sum'})
        .join(pd.crosstab(df['group'], df['categorical']), on='group'))

print (df)
    group  numerical  cat1  cat2
0  group1         64     2     1
1  group2         77     1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
out = pd.concat([df.groupby('group')['numerical'].sum().rename('numerical_sum'),
                 df.value_counts(['group', 'categorical']).unstack()
                   .add_prefix('categorical_').add_suffix('_size')],
                axis=1).reset_index()
print(out)

# Output
    group  numerical_sum  categorical_cat1_size  categorical_cat2_size
0  group1             64                      2                      1
1  group2             77                      1                      2
```